# How do I know if my vote has been registered?

Tags: support, election

I have ordered the four candidates in the current election, but there seems to be no mechanism to check and then confirm/finalize my vote.

There is a note that my choices have been “saved” but what is that supposed to mean?

Has my vote been recorded or not?

Answer (score 10):

There's a "pending save" countdown (in blue) after you make changes that tells you when your vote(s) will be saved. When it says "selections saved" (in black), it's saved. On desktop this is located next to "Your ballot" but on mobile it's higher up, underneath "*N* candidates" (and disappears after about 10 seconds).

You can refresh the page, and if your choices are still where you left them, you're good to go. (Otherwise, try again.) This is a little faster than waiting for the badge, and also works after you get the badge if you want to change your rankings.

This is, admittedly, a workaround. Many people find the current indication unclear and want it to be changed. See the Meta SE feature request [Introduce a clear visual indicator that confirms that one's vote counts in the election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371303/323179).

### Desktop:

[image: saving on desktop in sidebar: "your ballot ... pending save imminent"]

### Mobile:

[image: saving on mobile: "N candidates ... pending save in 1"]

Comment: I was using my phone and didn’t see any of this. I suspect poor support for mobile is the problem.

Comment: @David That's important context. On mobile it's located too far away and also disappears after several seconds (a usability anti-pattern). See edit.

Comment: I guess a number of votes may be lost given this unintuitive system.

Comment: @Gio If people can puzzle about whether or not their vote saved for 10 seconds, then nothing will be lost. I doubt that there's anything else that can be done for this election (don't want to see hasty changes), but I hope it's fixed in the future.

Comment: @Laurel When an anti-pattern is so bad that the problem disappears due to the user hesitating out of confusion, it's some kind of Zen-ti-pattern.

Comment: Refreshing the page or visiting again after going to a different site is the quicker way to check if the votes have been saved.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the only way to know if you have voted is to wait and see if you get [the Constituent badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/116/constituent).

There must be a better way.

Comment: You're right, they should make it more clear that a vote occurred successfully.